# Is a "Hard Coded" user agent enough for a program to work on multiple computers?

Tags: http, authentication, user-agent

I'm using **idHttp** to login to some sites and download a few files, and I was wondering since my program is going to be run on multiple computers with different windows and softwares when I say for example:

```
idHttp.userAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36 OPR/38.0.2220.41';
```

Is it enough? Or do I have to somehow extract the correct useragent information of that computer from somewhere and send that? I mean is a **hard coded** user agent the way to go and enough for a program to be compatible on multiple computers?

Comment: Huh, are you serious? Please consider developing a minimal understanding about this string.

Comment: @FreeConsulting you are indeed right, i do not know anything about useragents, i just want to know if they need to be dynamic and change with each system and windows for a program to work perfectly or not

Comment: You can start by looking at the stackoverflow help page for [user agents](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/user-agent/info). The little I know about it is that the user agent is used to indentify what software is making the request and tailor the result to that specific software. Think of a difference in layout for mobile web pages as opposed to standard pages. In the end, it's just a hint from the client to the server. The server uses or ignores the information as he pleases.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers thx for the help link, if a server does not ignore the information, is it possible for it to return an error ? , if so is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: No, hardcoded string mimicking common browser is usually fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> login to some sites and download a few files

By this you're most likely dealing with cookies. This is a difference to i.e. search engines which want to index the internet and more or less request anything, without having credentials to log in anywhere.

> my program is going to be run on multiple computers with different windows and softwares

This is irrelevant to your program.

> 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36 OPR/38.0.2220.41'

By this the server expects you being able to behave just like the internet browsers you're naming. Which you obviously won't.

In your case you don't have an interactive internet browser - you have an automated bot, and those should have an appropriate useragent. If you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Format_for_automated_agents_.28bots.29 you'll see that a useragent like this would be more fitting to your program: website owners can identify you (which can have both advantages and disadvantages) and also look up more about your purpose under the URI you're giving them:

```
MyProgram/1.0 (+http://myprogram.org/what_i_am_doing.html)
```

Comment: good answer, can you explain more about the `advantages and disadvantages` and ill accept your answer, thx

Comment: Advantage: cooperative site owners can skip/omit website output that you'll never deal with anyway, hence saving bandwidth/resources. Disadvantage: uncooperative site owners block non-internet-browser lookalikes generically. Best thing is always to explain site owners your goal and how they'd be able to recognize you and optimize output accordingly - if they decline or don't understand you can still fall back to "being Firefox".