# Load a png image from the web (delphi fmx)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I would like to load png images from the web, but with the code below not all images do get correctly into the stream (while posting the url in a webbrowser, e.g. edge, does give the image correctly).  For example, the first url in the code gives a loading bitmap failed error (in the stream FSize is only 14?), while the second url does not give a problem.  Does anyone know how to download the first url correctly?

For this piece of code to work, a TButton and a TImage was put on a form.
System.Net.HttpClientComponent was added in the uses.  I am using Delphi 10.3.3. fmx.

Thanks,
Gerard

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var ms: TmemoryStream;
        httpCli: TNetHTTPClient;
        url: string;
    begin
      httpCli := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create();
    
      url := 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/11/1050/674.png';
  //  url := 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Japan_small_icon.png';
    
      httpCli.Get(url,ms);
      ms.Position := 0;
      Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(ms);
    
      ms.free;
      httpCli.free;
    end;
```

Comment: You said there is some data being loaded into the stream for the first url, if it is not a valid image then what data is it exactly?

Comment: It is a valid image as can be seen by copying the url in a browser.

Comment: 14 bytes is likely not enough for a valid image. What do the bytes actually look like?

Comment: The issue is that the server blocks the User-Agent. See [here](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/72225/http-error-403-forbidden-accessing-tile) for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with the OpenStreetMap tile server is the UserAgent. You must change the default value to something acceptable by the server. I checked a number of possibilities and it looks like almost anything but default value of `TNetHTTPClient` works. See this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) for details.

To do that, you need to add the line

```
httpCli.UserAgent := 'Delphi/4.0 (compatible; Delphi; HttpClient)';
```

My version of your code which includes HTTP status code checking is the following:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    ms       : TMemoryStream;
    httpCli  : TNetHTTPClient;
    resp     : IHTTPResponse;
    url      : String;
begin
    httpCli := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
    try
        httpCli.UserAgent := 'Delphi/4.0 (compatible; Delphi; HttpClient)';
        ms := TMemoryStream.Create();
        try
            url  := 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/11/1050/674.png';
            resp := httpCli.Get(url, ms);
            if resp.StatusCode <> 200 then
                Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('HTTP Error=%d %s',
                                       [resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusText]))
            else begin
                ms.Position := 0;
                Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(ms);
            end;
        finally
            ms.Free;
        end;
    finally
        httpCli.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: *"You must change it so that you pretend to be a well known browser such as Mozilla"* This is forbidden by the [policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/): *"Valid HTTP User-Agent identifying application. Faking another app’s User-Agent WILL get you blocked."* You should choose your own User-Agent, specific to your app.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  By adding your own UserAgent string so the OSM server can identify your application (not using the exact useragent string of another application), it will be able to download correctly and the server can verify that you are using it within policy.

Comment: @fpiette: Two non-optional `try..finally` blocks are missing.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Sure. I just added the required fix for the OP question. It is not a whole example of how to program with Delphi. But for your pleasure, I will add it.

Comment: Thank you. In general, I fear that new Delphi devs might observe that experienced devs omit these blocks on SO and then draw the incorrect conclusion that they aren't necessary in real code either.

Comment: The useragent should adhere to how bots identify, see [my answer and the comments below about hardcoded useragents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40103319/4299358). Moreover your client surely is not `compatible` since it has no renderer at all. The useragent should be `MyProgram/1.0 (+https://myprogram.org/what_i_am_doing.html) `

Answer (score 1):

When operating on HTTP you have to check if the HTTP server can satisfy your request ([status code 200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_success), as per [RFC7231, § 6.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.3.1)) or any error occured. In your case requesting that URI and making sure to see what comes from the server can be done with i.e. [wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget):

```
wget -S --content-on-error https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/11/1050/674.png
```

This will print the server's response headers and in any case create a file that will hold the payload. The response headers are (excerpt):

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Length: 14
```

Which means: you are not allowed to query that resource (HTTP status code 403). The payload is saved in a file sizing 14 bytes, containing this text in 14 ASCII characters:

```
Access denied.
```

---

Trivia: the smallest valid PNG file sizes at least 67 bytes (read ["Smallest possible transparent PNG" by Gareth Rees](https://garethrees.org/2007/11/14/pngcrush/).

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of fpiete's answer. I found this way simpler, with no need to create the `TMemoryStream` object, for example.

You can use the [RESTRequest4D](https://github.com/viniciussanchez/RESTRequest4Delphi) library for the request. The usage is very simple and I find it more intuitive than the regular HTTP client.

```
procedure TQRCodeForm.LoadImageFromURL;
var
  LResponse: IResponse;
begin
  LResponse := TRequest
              .New
              .BaseURL(ImageURL)
              .Get;
  if LResponse.StatusCode = 200 then
  begin
    MyTImage.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(LResponse.ContentStream);
  end;
end;
```